# Vector<char*> push_back overwrites all entries

Tags: c++, vector, char, fgets, push-back

I want to use the push_back function to fill my vector with lines from a text file. But it overwrites all entries with the last line. Here is the source code:

```
  int main() {
    std::vector<char*> lines;
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
    const size_t max_line_length = 1000;
    char line[max_line_length + 1];
    while ( !feof(file)) {
      fgets(line, max_line_length, file);
      lines.push_back(line);
    }
    fclose(file);
 }
```

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use fstream and std::string?

Comment: @milleniumbug He'd probably make the same mistake with them.  `feof()` isn't predictive, so you have to test _after_ each input, not before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overwriting Line, and that's actually the only thing your are storing, since you never make deep copies. Try this instead:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lines; // <- change this!
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
    const size_t max_line_length = 1000;
    char line[max_line_length + 1];
    while ( !feof(file)) {
      fgets(line, max_line_length, file);
      lines.push_back(line);
    }
    fclose(file);
 }
```

Comment: You'll still get an extra line in the array (probably, anyway---it's not really specified).  `feof` is very much like `std::basic_ios<>::eof()`; it's only use is _after_ an input has failed.  The loop should be `while ( fgets( line, max_line_length, file ) )`

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same buffer (`line`) into every position of the vector.  You'll need to either:

1. reallocate a new char* for every line using `new`
2. use `strdup` to copy the `line` buffer on every line
3. use std::string as @milleniumbug suggested (my favorite)